# Visual studio recompile single file each time

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Is there any way to recompile one file each time project is compiled? I have about 200 cpp files in project and I have minimal rebuild - vs is recompiling only modified files, but one file needs to be recompiled each time I compile project, because it contains timestamp and few things which are compile time dependent, is there any way to mark any file with 'force recompile' flag? I know I can add space and remove it in this file each time I compile project, but I need way to do it automatically.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add a [custom pre-build event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h7dhf0ty.aspx) for the project. In this step do something to [change the timestamp](https://superuser.com/questions/10426/windows-equivalent-of-the-linux-command-touch) of the file you are interested in. (For example copy the file contents into same file)

[image]

Comment: it's perfect solution!